# Import CSV code with insert post and post meta tables?

Tags: wordpress

I have created one plugin **`import.php`**

```
 <?php
function fileupload_process() {
  ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
  set_time_limit(0);
  $uploadfiles = $_FILES['uploadfiles'];
  //echo 'ddd';
 // exit;
  if (is_array($uploadfiles)) {
 //echo 'ram';
 //print_r($uploadfiles);
 echo $uploadfiles['name'];
   // foreach ($uploadfiles as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($uploadfiles['name'] as $key => $value) {
      // look only for uploaded files
      if ($uploadfiles['error'][$key] == 0) {
        $filetmp = $uploadfiles['tmp_name'][$key];
        if (($handle = fopen($filetmp, "r")) !== FALSE) {
          $flag = true;
          $songs = explode("\n",file_get_contents($filetmp));
          $count = count( $songs );
          unset($songs);
          echo "Total item count: " . $count . "<BR />";
          // typical entry: If You Have To Ask,Red Hot Chili Peppers,0:03:37, Rock & Alternative,1991,on
          // using a generous 1000 length - will lowering this actually impact performance in terms of memory allocation?
          while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            // Skip the first entry in the csv containing colmn info
            if($flag) {
                      $flag = false; 
              echo "<BR />"; 
              $count--; 
              continue; 
            }
            // insert the current post and relevant info into the database
            $currently_processed = process_custom_post($data);
            $count--;
          }
          echo "Done!";
          fclose($handle);
        }
        unlink($filetmp); // delete the temp csv file
      }
    }
  }
} // END: file_upload_process()
function process_custom_post($song) {
  global $wpdb;

  // Prepare and insert the custom post
  $track =  (array_key_exists(0, $song) && $song[0] != "" ?  $song[0] : 'N/A');
  $custom_post = array();
  $custom_post['post_type'] = 'songs';
  $custom_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
  $custom_post['post_title'] = $track;
  $post_id = wp_insert_post( $custom_post );

  // Prepare and insert the custom post meta
  $meta_keys = array();
  $meta_keys['artist_name'] = (array_key_exists(1, $song) && $song[1] != ""  ?  $song[1] : 'N/A');
  $meta_keys['song_length'] = (array_key_exists(2, $song) && $song[2] != ""  ?  $song[2] : 'N/A');
  $meta_keys['song_genre'] = (array_key_exists(3, $song) && $song[3] != ""  ?  $song[3] : 'N/A');
  $meta_keys['song_year'] = (array_key_exists(4, $song) && $song[4] != ""  ?  $song[4] : 'N/A');
  $meta_keys['song_month'] = (array_key_exists(5, $song) && $song[5] != ""  ?  $song[5] : 'N/A');
  $meta_keys['sample_playlist'] = (array_key_exists(6, $song) && $song[6] != ""  ?  $song[6] : '');
  $custom_fields = array();
  $place_holders = array();
  $query_string = "INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ";
  foreach($meta_keys as $key => $value) {
     array_push($custom_fields, $post_id, $key, $value);
     $place_holders[] = "('%d', '%s', '%s')";
  }
  $query_string .= implode(', ', $place_holders);
  $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("$query_string ", $custom_fields));
  return true;
}// END: process_custom_post()
function import_page () {
//HTML for the import page + the file upload form
  if (isset($_POST['uploadfile'])) {
    fileupload_process();
       }
}
```

In **`main.php`** I do customize the code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: csv ram
Plugin URI: http://www.newdreamdatasystems.com
Description: csv ram
Version: 2.0
Author: RAM KUMAR
Author URI: http://www.newdreamdatasystems.com
*/
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_ROOT' , dirname(__FILE__) );
include_once( MY_PLUGIN_ROOT . '/import.php');
$ram = import_page();

add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page');

function register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'manage_options', 'my-custom-submenu-page', 'my_custom_submenu_page_callback' ); 
}

function my_custom_submenu_page_callback() {
$html= <<<RAM
<form action="{$ram}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1" onSubmit="">
    <label>upload file<input type="file" name="uploadfiles" id="uploadfiles" /></label>

    <label><input type="submit" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" value="Submit" /></label>
</form>
RAM;
echo $html;
}
```

But I have one error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\try\import.php on line 13..?

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Three main problems:

- The function `import_page()` should be run inside the callback:

  ```
  function my_custom_submenu_page_callback() {
      import_page();
      /* etc */
  }
  ```
- Action `<form action="">` should be empty, so it goes back to the same plugin page, `/wp-admin/tools.php?page=my-custom-submenu-page`.
- The file field should allow for multiple uploads so this will work `foreach ($uploadfiles as $key => $value)` and remove the error you're seeing.

  ```
  <input type="file" name="uploadfiles[]" id="uploadfiles" multiple />
  ```

  Thinking better, you may not need the `multiple` attribute, but then adjust the rest of the logic.

But after this adjustments, there are still a bunch of notices and warnings, like `Array to string conversion`, `Undefined index: name` and `fopen(): Filename cannot be empty`.

All this is easily fixed with careful debugging, this is how I found the 3 problems above:

- Add ***`printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $INSPECT_VAR, true ) );`*** to go inspecting the problematic variables.